Firebase project issue with GAE
I recently hit the following issue on a firebase project of mine.
When running this command:
% firebase deploy --only functions

I end up with this error at the end:

There was an issue deploying your functions. Verify that your project has a
Google App Engine instance setup at https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine
and try again. If this issue persists, please contact support.
⚠  functions: Upload Error: HTTP Error: 403, Write access
to project 'myproject-8d760' was denied: please check billing account
associated and retry

I had never seen this before. Though I have run many times the commands:
% firebase deploy --only functions
% firebase deploy --only hosting

Removing the most recent changes in my code does not change anything.
I went to take a look at https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine, but it seems like I may have to spend a lot of time there.
Is there a simple way to solve this issue and quickly get back to my project development ?
Any help would be very much appreciated.

If you're unable to deploy with an error message that doesn't seem actionable, you should reach out to Firebase support.

Just in case this happens to someone else.
That was a dumb reason for the issue. I had some pending payment waiting.
Once solved, the problem disappeared.
